# how to cross compile LLVM with CMAKE for Android-NDK?

Tags: android-ndk, cmake, llvm, cross-compiling

i am using CMake compilation and defining {CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME}; so the {CMAKE_CROSSCOMPILING} definition gets turned ON;

however; i see that finally the LLVM tools < llvm-xxx, opt , ... > are not being built for the native host;

what do i miss here? i was thinking that everything should be built twice, for native and for target.

Example:
for building two versions of clang-tblgen; LLVM defines another target NATIVEClangTableGen (defined at TableGen.cmake); which produces clang-table gen under native/... whenever clang is built.
However; the same behavior doesn't apply to LLVM tools; where the there is no such thing, NATIVEXXX corresponding target;

So, if CMake procuduces one target, such as llvm-link whenever CMAKE_CROSSCOMPILING is ON; it won't produce the same target for native; since it's thinking that the target has been created already.

any ideas how to make this work?

Comment: Hi - can you give some more details? - would be really handy to see the script you are running, for example...

Comment: I cannot give a script here; it's part of the LLVM source tree CMakeLists.txt files already. I added more explanation of the problem above.